# Arduino Nano 3.0 dimensions without the pins

Tags: arduino-nano

I think the title of this question is quite clear. I am looking for the exact dimensions of the Arduino Nano 3.0, with the electronic components and the USB mini port on the IC (the Atmega328 one), without the external pins.

Comment: It'll be 1.6mm plus the thickness of the thickest component - which you can find in the datasheet for that component - plus a tiny bit for solder float.

Answer (score 1):

Mini-USB-B is around 4mm tall.

Most PCBs are around 1.6mm.

The FT232RL on the bottom is 2mm (max) according to the datasheet. (voltage regulator is 1.8mm). (I'm sure about this tantalum capacitors)

So that's something around 7.6mm total height

Comment: What about the components on the bottom?

Comment: @user29519 sorry about that. I always mix up those boards. I thought the nano used the ATMega32u4.

Answer (score 1):

I have a nano so let me get a ruler, ok. The usb port takes up most of the room so 4mms, the board itself is 1mm and a tiny chip adds 2mms as well. So 7mms! Hope this helped!